# Regression problem, how to interpret result from baseline, when using L1, L2 and R2

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, random-forest

I'm trying to interpret results from a regression problem I have been working on. The project is about estimating waiting time in an emergency department. I have in the beginning created a baseline, which is the median of the waiting time from the dataset. This baseline is used as a ground base where the objective is that the models should beat the baseline ofc.

I have used Linear regression and Random Forest and calculated the L1 norm, L2 norm and R2 values. How do I know which of the three should weight the highest when deciding which model to choose is better? or is it even possible?

The results showed a rather low score of R2, below 0.10, furthermore, L1 seemed not to beat baseline, but L2 was better in every model.

I know my data is not good, this was also validated by visualising the independent variables vs the dependent (the waiting time), but having trouble choosing which model to choose (if one should be chosen).

Answer (score 0):

Those are not real performance values. Use standard performance metrics such as accuracy or MSE, for classification and regression respectively. You can estimate these using Cross Validation or a separate test set.

Comment: l1 = MAE and l2 = MSE, so thanks for bad feedback.

And they are metrics for regression --> https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-select-the-right-evaluation-metric-for-machine-learning-models-part-1-regrression-metrics-3606e25beae0

Comment: @Ray I have never seen them being called that, you are using uncommon terminology. Anyway, what metric you use depends on your objective, however for regression MSE is standard, so unless you have some knowledge on why some other metric would be a better option you should stick with the standard.